# what is alternative of .attrs in material ui 5 with styled-components as styled-engine

Tags: material-ui, attributes, styled-components, class-names

This is how we add className to a styled-component

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
export const FieldsColumnWrapper = styled.div.attrs({
  className: 'components-list column',
})`
  grid-area: components-list;
  display: flex;
`
```

We can use attrs function to pass this className = components-list column, whenever this component is rendered., the classname `component-list column` is present in the div
However if use styled-component as styled engine for mui 5, and then code is modified as below

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
export const Wrapper = styled('div', {
  name: 'form-builder',
  slot: 'form-builder',
}) `
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'components-list forms-list field-config-editor';
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 450px;
`
```

I want to know what should I use on the styled coming from `@mui/material/styles`, that will allow me to add className on the HTML element created by the component?

Comment: You can directly create **className** like `<Wrapper className='form-builder'`

Comment: yes, that is doable, I am looking for something, so that we do not have to give this className prop, repeatedly

Answer (score 1):

'.attrs' API is not yet added in MUI v5. If you want to achieve the same behaviour, you can do this,

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const Wrapper = styled('div')`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'components-list forms-list field-config-editor';
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 450px;
`;

Wrapper.defaultProps = {
  name: 'form-builder',
  slot: 'form-builder',
};
```

You can refer more about this issue here
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29492